# QTable : how to identify leaving a row

Tags: qt

I have a basic question about the usage of QTable. Consider the following example. I would like to create a table with three columns - Name, Age and weight. An "add" button should be able to add a row in the table. The newly added row show be completely edited before leaving (i.e. all the three columns should be edited). Is there a signal which indicates that the complete row is left or the control is no more there in current row?
 Such a signal will help me to put some error checking on the input values (e.g. checking if age is a positive no.) in all three columns (also to ensure that none of them is empty). Since this seems to be a very basic requirement, I think I am either missing the signal or the mechanism to support such working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of QTable you should use QTableWidget or QTableView.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/porting4.html#qtable

Now, responding to your question.

Have you tried using the  [itemSelectionChanged()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) or [itemEntered()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemEntered) signals?

Another way to do it would be to use the signal cellActivated() or the signal fired by your "Add" button - to indicate that the edit has started. Then you setup a connection to catch the next mouse button click or Return key pressed signals to detect the editing ended.

Edit: 
I suppose that in your app you subclass QMainWindow or QWidget, if so, reimplement QWidget::mouseMoveEvent and/or QWidget::keyPressedEvent to detect when the left mouse button was clicked  ( use keyPressedEvent to detect when the Return Key is pressed ).

You can read more about events in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html

Comment: I think none of this could be useful for me as we are stuck here with qt 3.3.8. Currently, I am using another way that I mentioned in below answer.

Comment: I am using valuechanged() signal but that is only helpful in cases where a real edit has been made in the table. I still don't know how to identify for example, if someone creates a new row in table (with the help of Add button) and then just clicks somewhere else in the application. Will there be a signal in such cases?