# how to use QTable::editCell()

Tags: qt

I don't understand how QTable::editCell() should be used. I am trying to do some error checking based on entries made by user in a QTable as mentioned in [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731075/qtable-how-to-identify-leaving-a-row).

I would like to give user an opportunity to re-edit the cell which has error. For example, if name column entry has some special characters such as '(', the user should be prompted for the error and the control should go back to same cell in edit mode. I tried using QTable::editCell() in my code as shown below.

```
Table->editCell(row, 0, TRUE);
name = Table->text(row, 0);
```

However, this doesn't work as expected. The control doesn't stay in the cell at all and obviously the `name` is not correctly collected. So, my question is how to ensure from within code that a cell of QTable can be edited so that the edited contents can be accessed immediately in next statement (as shown in above code).

**Note**: I am working with qt 3.3.8 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. You'll have to go back to the event loop, and wait for one of the signals (like `valueChanged(row,col)`) to be fired to re-validate the data.

A blocking wait on a GUI object is often not a good approach (except for modal dialogs).

Comment: So, what is the standard usage of editcell. So, you seem to suggest that fetching of value from a cell should only happen from a slot and not immediately after editCell call.

Comment: `editCell` "Starts editing the cell at row, col" according to the docs. It does not wait for that editing to be done - that is notified by a signal. Having `editCell` wait for anything would block the event loop without some tricky code and/or threading, which is not desirable. You should not "busy-wait" for GUI actions (except for the special case of modal dialogs that are expected to "freeze" the main window.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late here but you should use the following connect statement with your own custom function to do your specific needs such as below. You can also use this method to disable users from entering in special characters within you custom function. That way they wont ever have to correct undesirable characters.

```
connect(ui->tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int,int)), this, SLOT(customFunction(int,int)));

void updateTable
{
    //remove invalid characters
}
```